# Cant get email form to work

Tags: html, forms

So I am trying to add a form to my portfolio where you put in your name, email and a message. You can then click send and it sends it to my address, however when I press send nothing happens, any help? This is the code that Im using(obviously i use my actual email in the real code but dont want to post it here):

```
<form action="mailto:myemail@place.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                    Name:<br />
                <input type="text" name="name"><br />
                    E-mail:<br />
                <input type="text" name="mail"><br />
                    Comment:<br />
                <input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            </form>
```

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-create-contact-form-html.html

Comment: Im using chrome

Comment: Also I would use a php sheet but this is gonna be marked for part of my course and were only allowed to use HTML, CSS and JS so is there any way for it to work without using PHP?